# Laravel 5.3: Database driven services.php in config directory

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am would like to drive some of the configuration variables in `services.php` driven by a database.

Basically, I am using a service provider and a facade that will be used by different customers on the same platform. However, for each customer the variable would be unique.

For example, let's say I have a service provider called "mypost", that works with a third party api. Every customer has their own "mypost" secret key generated. If this were a single tenant application I would use an env variable as shown below:

```
'mypost' => [ 'secret' => env('MYPOST_SECRET'), ],
```

However, I am building a multi-tenant application. I would like it to work as follows:

```
'mypost' => [ 'secret' => $customersecret, ],
```

The value of `$customersecret` is stored in a database and varies based on the customer interacting with the app.

Any thoughts on how to go about it?

Comment: You probably don't want to be storing a user specific variable as an environment variable. That's not the point of `env`. Just read it from the DB.

Comment: hi apokryfos - are you suggesting that I should completely skip the services.php and use a factory in the controller instead?  or can I use query builder i.e. DB::table in the services.php in my config directory?

Comment: Well I don't really know what you are doing since you haven't shared any code but I'd say you should access the database in all parts where you would otherwise have used `env` to get this variable. At the same time if this refers to a signed in user there's also the `$request->user()` you could use.

Comment: @apokryfos - as explained in my post what I do is get the user id and based on the user id - I get the value of $customerscret that is stored in my database. Then this value is passed to my controller for initializing a function call.  Sorry not code because it is a customer app and I am not allowed to post any code.